# How to change the Use Photo title to Use of UIImagePickerController in ios

Tags: ios

I have a part in my app in which users can take a quick photo and save it to the camera roll. After the photo has been taken, down the bottom it says "Retake" and "Use Photo". I want that Use Photo as "Use".Is there anyway to do this.